# Opencart 3: Increase Information Pages line-height?

Tags: css, opencart-3

I have several information pages in Opencart 3 and the text lines are too close together; almost overlapping. Where can I find the css to change the line-height?

Maybe i missed something but I have gone through the css files in the admin folder and nothing seems to do it.

Note also, editing the source in the information page editor does nothing. Making any changes to that source results in the text returning to its, I guess, css setting.

Comment: please mention your information page live demo link. So, will realize. what is exactly issue there.

Comment: Are you using default theme?

Comment: I am using Journal theme but it's the same in the default theme too. Still haven't found an answer to this. Any suggestions appreciated.